# Return Partial View in Ajax Success Call with Fetched Json Data

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am fetching JSON data via an AJAX call to a controller within an ASP.NET MVC project.  I am able to get the JSON data from the Web API call just fine.  Now I want to take this JSON data that is returned to the `success` function within my AJAX call and pass it to a partial view instead of statically appending JSON data with jQuery.

**C# Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("company-info/companyinfogetapidata")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult CompanyInfoGetApiData(string name, int CompanyCode, string city, string state, int zip)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("URL_BASE");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var request = client.GetAsync("URL_PATH");                
        var json = request.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

        JToken ApiData = o["results"];

       // Here is where I want to insert pieces of the JSON data into the model and then pass it into the partial view
        CompanyResultsModel getfetcheddata = new CompanyResultsModel();

        getfetcheddata = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CompanyResultsModel>(json);


        return PartialView(@"~/Views/Shared/companies/_companyResults.cshtml", getfetcheddata);

    }
```

**EDIT:** I created a new model below
`CompanyResultsModel:`

```
namespace Companies.Models
{
    public class CompanyResultsModel
    {
        public string companyName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**AJAX Call:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"../companyinfogetapidata",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {DATA HERE},
    error:function(e){alert("nope"+e);},
    success: function (xhr_request) {

        var fetched_data = xhr_request["results"];

        var i;

        var iLength = fetched_data.length;

        for (i = 0; i < iLength; i++) {
            // This was the original jQuery way I was appending the JSON data
            // $("#CompanyFinderResultsContainer").append("<p>Name:&nbsp;" + fetched_data[i].name + "</p>");
            // I want to call a Partial View and Pass along the JSON data from this success function
            // I am thinking of making a call like this                            
            @Html.Partial("_CompanyFinderResults", Model);

        }


    }
});
```

I tried following a few methods of creating a model within the controller to append this JSON data but I'm not quite sure if this is the best approach.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After editing your AJAX section, I think I see an easier way to do what you're trying to accomplish.

You'll want your controller to return a `PartialViewResult` so that `HTML` is communicated to your front end:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("company-info/companyinfogetapidata")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public PartialViewResult CompanyInfoGetApiData(string name, int CompanyCode, string city, string state, int zip)
{

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("URL_BASE");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var request = client.GetAsync("URL_PATH");                
    var json = request.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

    return PartialView(@"_CompanyFinderResults.cshtml", Model);

}
```

Note the `Return Type` of the Controller method.

You can then move the `for loop` you were using in your `AJAX success` function into your `_CompanyFinderResults.cshtml` and let the `MVC View Engine` do that processing for you.

Then adjust your `AJAX success` function to handle the returned `PartialViewData`:

```
     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"../companyinfogetapidata",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {DATA HERE},
            error:function(e){alert("nope"+e);},
            success: function (partialViewData) {
                $('#your-div-to-hold-partial-view').html(partialViewData);
            }
        });
```

**Edit:** So I believe you have 3 options for an approach here:

**1.** You can have your AJAX call trigger a second AJAX call to retrieve a `PartialView` to update a `div` in your HTML.

**2.** You can have your existing AJAX call return a `PartialView` to update a `div` in your HTML.

**3.** You can write JavaScript in the `success function` of your AJAX call to build your desired HTML for updating a `div` in your HTML.

I recommend the second option, which is what my answer is geared towards. It appears to be the most efficient solution for your goals.

I don't recommend the third option as it will require a lot of `string concatenation` which will be very unmanageable code. But it will be easier to develop since you won't have to interact with the `MVC framework` as much as you would in the other options.

I can show you how to do any of these solutions if you would like.

Comment: I'm trying to modify my code but am having issues with the return line `return PartialView(@"_CompanyFinderResults.cshtml", Model);` where I'm assuming I want to take this JSON data and store it into this `Model` variable.

Comment: So that `Model` variable should be there model that your `PartialView` needs to create your `View`. In your original `AJAX` section, you had `@Html.Partial("_CompanyFinderResults", Model);`, this `Model` variable refers to that one.

Comment: I wasn't actually using that line of code, it was just a suggestion I had.  What I really want to do is take that parsed JSON data from the controller and pass it into the partialView.

Comment: Is there a reason that you need the data to get passed back to your JavaScript? It might be more efficient to just process your partial view right after you process your data in your controller.

Comment: I'm actually really close to getting this to work properly.  See my edit above to see what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: So I think the thing that you are missing is that the `@Html.Partial("_CompanyFinderResults", Model);` line isn't going to be processed quite how you want. That line is processed before your view loads, it doesn't process when your AJAX call is triggered. To have that line be processed after your AJAX call, you'll need to make a new method on your controller and have a second AJAX call that fires on the success of your first one.
If you only want one AJAX call, then you can refer to my posted answer for that solution.

Comment: @JeffP. I added an **Edit** section on my answer with some options for you