# Partial View not showing updated model values. Always shows existing values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-ajax

Actually i tried to update the partial view content whenever i do search. So i use ajax call to achieve this. So, the values from the controller to partial view model is correct(new data), but its not binding to the view (shows existing data).

**Main View**

```
     <div class="tab-pane active" id="partialviewpage">
          @{
             Html.RenderPartial("_Details", Model);
           }
      </div>
```

**Partial View (_Details)**

```
   foreach (var item in Model.AllAds)
    {
       //div contents
    }
```

**Ajax Call**

```
   var text = 'test';
   $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Subcategory", "Category")',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: { item: text },
        success: function (partialView) {
            $('#partialviewpage').html(partialView);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

        }
    });
```

**Category Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Subcategory(string item)
    {
      //Logic calling Api content goes here

      var SearchresponseData = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
      JavaScriptSerializer JssSearch = new JavaScriptSerializer();
      List<Result> Jsonresult =       (List<Result>)JssSearch.Deserialize(SearchresponseData, typeof(List<Result>));
      var Model= new ModelName();
        {
            Model.AllAds = new List<Result>();
            Model.AllAds = Jsonresult;
        }
      return PartialView("_Details", Model);
    }
```

So, What's wrong with my code and how can i modify the code to get the new model values. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume `success: function (PartialView) {` is a typo and its really `partialView` (lower case `p`)?

Comment: have you check in console for any js error, have you check on network tab for data is returning correct, have you check if data is returning correct than any binding issue like selector etc.

Comment: And the code in your controller method does not even compile!

Comment: There is no error in network tab @programtreasures

Comment: @Muzz have you check in network tab the response data is updated?

Comment: Yeah, i checked. I got the updated data in response. @programtreasures

Comment: @Muzz so now the issue with replacing the html, Can you please make sure you are using the correct selector?

Comment: You mean the div to bind the result right ?. Its correct @programtreasures

Comment: @Muzz got an issue?

Comment: what is the response you are getting in ajax call?

Comment: @Aamir i am getting status 200 and when i check for the response tab in network the new model values is replaced existing model values.

Comment: if the response is html, you need to check if jquery is doing any processing, maybe try processData:false in ajax options. you can also test by simply writing document.write(partialView).. just to check

Comment: You are setting the dataType to json, that is telling the ajax call what you expect to get back. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Aamir  Yeah the response is HTML. When i try to set processData: false even the html also not returning.

Comment: @EmmaMiddlebrook Yeah its JSON, when i try datatype : html, the whole page comes under partialview

Comment: @Muzz Have you tried setting the return type of your action to PartialViewResult? See the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798397/return-partial-view-in-ajax-success-call-with-fetched-json-data?rq=1

Comment: How do you trigger the ajax call? on a certain click.. you can try MVC's default Ajax Helpers

Answer (score 0):

I observed that you have used wrong variable to replace the html in success,

I have replace `PartialView` to `partialView`

```
 var text = 'test';
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Subcategory", "Category")',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: { item: text },
    success: function (partialView) {
        $('#partialviewpage').html(partialView);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: If that were the issue, then its a simple typo and you should have voted to close, not add ab answer.

Comment: @StephenMuecke just give path to OP with modified code

Comment: After i change also, not getting the updated values. @programtreasures